# Can not import WebSocketStompClient class - STOMP + SockJS java Client

Tags: java, spring, maven, gradle

I am trying to create Java WebSocket client (STOMP + sockJs) following 
[this sample](https://github.com/rstoyanchev/spring-websocket-portfolio/blob/master/src/test/java/org/springframework/samples/portfolio/web/load/StompWebSocketLoadTestClient.java). But I am not able to find maven/gradle dependency for

```
org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.WebSocketStompClient
```

Even [maven search](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cfc%3Aorg.springframework.web.socket.messaging.WebSocketStompClient) did not give any results.

After some searching I found that this is a part of

> 4.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT

and the javadoc for this class is [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/socket/messaging/WebSocketStompClient.html).

I have tried to import

```
 org.springframework:spring-messaging:4.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT
```

and

```
 org.springframework:spring-web:4.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT
```

But I was not able to import this class. 
I want to know if it is possible to import the 4.2.0.BUILd-SNAPSHOT from gradle.

If it is possible how do I know which spring module (like spring-web / spring-messaging) from the javadoc?

**EDIT** : am I correct in assuming that it is part of 4.2.0 from the Javadoc URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the snapshot repository if you want to use them:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer :)
This is what I was looking for (though I found 4.2.0.RC1 later).

Comment: I have just seen your talk at at SpringOne2GX 2014.
If it is not too much to ask for, Could you please answer [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31108780/stomp-or-xmpp-over-websocket).

Answer (score 0):

Please add this in your POM.xml :Please match the version with your Spring-framework version.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-websocket</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Then do a mvn clean && mvn install from console if you are on linux or maven install from Eclipse.

Comment: If this didn't help you, let me know, I have few other suggestions.

Comment: Do you 4.2.0.RELEASE?

If so, it would not work since 4.2.0 is not into release yet. 

If not , It does not make sense to add 4.0.0.RELEASE as I am already using 4.1.6.RLEASE
 
I wanted to know how to use build-snapshot correctly.

Comment: Bhai, english sudharo, I cannot understand what you just said. You can use the above dependency, it is not an issue.

Comment: we are Borg Yeah, but I think first you should know what is the latest spring version.

Comment: Yes.. What is the spring version?? Are you using Spring 4.0? or you match the dependency.

Comment: Please read the question again, I want to use **4.2.0** snapshot, not 4.0.0

Comment: Why are you using Snapshot branch? You shouldnt... Promise me you will use 4.1.6.. :P

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81972/discussion-between-we-are-borg-and-karthik).

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to import 4.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT but I was able to import 4.2.0.RC1 release.

I checked the pom.xml of the [sample](https://github.com/rstoyanchev/spring-websocket-portfolio/blob/master/src/test/java/org/springframework/samples/portfolio/web/load/StompWebSocketLoadTestClient.java) and just imported the same version as it is.